# Why is this plain array implementation slower than the std::vector implementation performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, stl

Why is this plain array implementation slower than the std::vector implementation performance?

Due to some weired results I was seeing on something I'm working on, I decided to write a simplified test to compare `std::vector` vs plain array efficiency.

I have a struct which I implement in both ways,

#### 1 using plain arrays (of different sizes)

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t index;
     uint16_t nvals;
     uint16_t vals[50];
     double mean;
} a_segment_t;
```

#### 2 using STL

```
 typedef struct {
      uint16_t index;
      uint16_t nvals;
      vector<uint16_t> vals;
      uint32_t mean;
} b_segment_t;
```

The creation of this object in memory is not what I'm interested in (so I dont mind the `push_back()`), once this object is in memory it is used for an *operation* and that efficiency is what I'm analyzing. The `vals` are filled with some random data.

The *operation* goes through the vals stored in each segment, in this case a simple mean calculation. The test is as follows:

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // srand, rand
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#define NSEGMENTS 100
#define MAX_NPXS 50
#define N 10000

// plain array approach
typedef struct {
    uint16_t index;
    uint16_t nvals;
    uint16_t vals[MAX_NPXS];
    double mean;
} a_segment_t;
uint16_t operation(uint16_t, a_segment_t*);
uint16_t print(uint16_t nsegments, a_segment_t* p_segments);

// stl vector approach
typedef struct {
    uint16_t index;
    uint16_t nvals;
    vector<uint16_t> vals;
    uint32_t mean;
} b_segment_t;
uint16_t operation(uint16_t, vector<b_segment_t>*);
uint16_t print(uint16_t nsegments, vector<b_segment_t>*);

void delta_time(struct timespec*, struct timespec*, struct timespec*);

uint16_t operation(uint16_t nsegments, a_segment_t* p_segments) {
    // the operation (plain array approach)
    uint64_t sum;
    for( uint16_t nsegment = 0; nsegment < nsegments; ++nsegment ) {
        sum = 0;
        for(uint16_t nval = 0; nval < p_segments[nsegment].nvals; ++nval){
            sum = sum + p_segments[nsegment].vals[nval];
        }
        p_segments[nsegment].mean = sum/p_segments[nsegment].nvals;
    }
    return nsegments;
}

uint16_t print(uint16_t nsegments, a_segment_t* p_segments) {
    // print data (plain array approach)
    for( uint16_t nsegment = 0; nsegment < nsegments; ++nsegment ) {
        cout << "index : " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << p_segments[nsegment].index;
        cout << "\tnval : " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << p_segments[nsegment].nvals;
        cout << "\tvals : [";
        for(uint16_t nval = 0; nval < p_segments[nsegment].nvals; ++nval){
            cout << p_segments[nsegment].vals[nval] << ",";
        }
        cout << "\b]" << endl;
    }
    return nsegments;
}

uint16_t operation(uint16_t nsegments, vector<b_segment_t>* p_segments) {
    // the operation (stl vector approach)
    uint32_t sum;
    for (vector<b_segment_t>::iterator p_segment = p_segments->begin(); p_segment<p_segments->end(); ++p_segment) {
        sum = 0;
        for (vector<uint16_t>::iterator p_val = (p_segment->vals).begin(); p_val<(p_segment->vals).end(); ++p_val) {
            sum = sum + (*p_val);
        }
        p_segment->mean = sum/(p_segment->nvals);
    }
    return nsegments;
}

uint16_t print(uint16_t nsegments, vector<b_segment_t>* p_segments) {
    // print data (stl vector approach)
    for (vector<b_segment_t>::iterator p_segment = p_segments->begin(); p_segment<p_segments->end(); ++p_segment) {
        cout << "index : " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << p_segment->index;
        cout << "\tnval : " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << p_segment->nvals;
        cout << "\tvals : [";
        for (vector<uint16_t>::iterator p_val = (p_segment->vals).begin(); p_val<(p_segment->vals).end(); ++p_val) {
            cout << *p_val << ",";
        }
        cout << "\b]" << endl;
    }
    return nsegments;
}

void delta_time(struct timespec* t1, struct timespec* t2, struct timespec* dt) {
    if ((t2->tv_nsec - t1->tv_nsec) < 0) {
        dt->tv_sec = t2->tv_sec - t1->tv_sec - 1;
        dt->tv_nsec = t2->tv_nsec - t1->tv_nsec + 1000000000;
    } else {
        dt->tv_sec = t2->tv_sec - t1->tv_sec;
        dt->tv_nsec = t2->tv_nsec - t1->tv_nsec;
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    uint16_t nsegments = NSEGMENTS;
    uint16_t nsegment = 0;
    uint16_t i = 0;

    //create an populate the segments with dummy data (plain array approach)
    a_segment_t* a_segments = new a_segment_t[nsegments];
    for( nsegment = 0; nsegment < nsegments; ++nsegment ) {
        a_segments[nsegment].index = nsegment;
        srand(nsegment);
        a_segments[nsegment].nvals = rand() % MAX_NPXS + 1;
        for(uint16_t nval = 0; nval < a_segments[nsegment].nvals; ++nval){
            a_segments[nsegment].vals[nval] = nval;
        }
    }

    //create an populate the segments with dummy data (stl vector approach)
    nsegment = 0;
    vector<b_segment_t> b_segments(nsegments);
    for (vector<b_segment_t>::iterator p_segment = b_segments.begin(); p_segment<b_segments.end(); ++p_segment) {
        p_segment->index = nsegment;
        srand(nsegment);
        p_segment->nvals = rand() % MAX_NPXS + 1;
        for(uint16_t nval = 0; nval < p_segment->nvals; ++nval){
            p_segment->vals.push_back(nval);
        }
        nsegment++;
    }

    // print(nsegments, a_segments);
    // cout << "===================================" << endl;

    // print(nsegments, &b_segments);
    // cout << "===================================" << endl;

    // ======================= plain array timing measure ========================
    struct timespec a_times[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        nsegments = operation(nsegments, a_segments);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(a_times[i]));
    }
    // ===========================================================================

    // ========================= vector timing measure ===========================
    struct timespec b_times[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        nsegments = operation(nsegments, &b_segments);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(b_times[i]));
    }
    // ===========================================================================

    // =========================== timing console log ============================
    struct timespec a_deltatime[N], a_elapsedtime[N], b_deltatime[N], b_elapsedtime[N];
    cout << "\t\t  plain array\t\t       stl vector" << endl;
    cout << "frame #\telapsedtime\tdeltatime\telapsedtime\tdeltatime" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < N-1; i=i+1000) {
        delta_time(&(a_times[0]), &(a_times[i]), &(a_elapsedtime[i]));
        delta_time(&(a_times[i]), &(a_times[i+1]), &(a_deltatime[i]));
        delta_time(&(b_times[0]), &(b_times[i]), &(b_elapsedtime[i]));
        delta_time(&(b_times[i]), &(b_times[i+1]), &(b_deltatime[i]));
        cout << i << ",\t"
        << a_elapsedtime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << a_elapsedtime[i].tv_nsec << ",\t"
        << a_deltatime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << a_deltatime[i].tv_nsec << ",\t"
        << b_elapsedtime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << b_elapsedtime[i].tv_nsec << ",\t"
        << b_deltatime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << b_deltatime[i].tv_nsec << endl;
    }
    // ===========================================================================

}
```

An [online version](http://cpp.sh/7lfsn). Note: All of the tests were compiled with -O3

- Can someone please point out why the plain array implementation is slower than the `std::vector` implementation?
- Shouldn't the plain array implementation be faster?
- What can I do to improve the speed of the plain array implementation?

Comment: *"Shouldn't the plain array implementation be faster?"* - I don't mean to be rude, but standard library implementations are usually worked on by groups of very smart people with decades of experience between them. Your naive implementation is unlikely to be as optimized out of the box.

Comment: What are the time differences? I could imagine that the `std::vector` implementation sees the array appropriately aligned to apply vector operations on the entire array whereas the plain array implementation most likely doesn't have the values aligned suitable for vectorization. However, without more details that is like a blind guy trying to shoot at a target in the dark.

Comment: No offense taken, I totally agree if this was a complicated algorithm. but this is simple exercise of array (or vector) traversal.

Comment: On a single core 512mb ram virtual machine for 9000 iterations 0.062658325 s (~0.0000058 s each) for the plain array implementation and 0.042909131 s (~0.0000042 s each) for the vector implementation.

Comment: It seems the measurements are taken for the actual computations only, i.e., they don't include allocation of the setup of the data structure. I'd claim that the [small] difference is indeed about the `std::vector` arrays being more likely properly aligned to compute more of the data using vector operations.

Comment: Actually, there also seems to be a spurious difference: the two implementations do *different* things! One of the implementations uses a `double` for the `mean` while the other uses `uint32_t`. You might want to start off making the two implementations do the same thing...

Comment: Also `uint32_t sum` in one case and `uint64_t sum` in the other. As per @DietmarKühl you need to do exactly the same things in both cases to have more accurate results.

Comment: Those two corrections of data types of `sum` and `mean were typos and fixing them did bring the two results to the same ballpark with the plain array being a tiny bit faster, as expected. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will do a much better job of optimising code if you express algorithms in terms of iterators. One of the reasons is that it can make assumptions about the size and overflow characteristics of array indexes (which translate to indexed addressing with offset in machine code).

Refactoring to express both `operation()` and `print()` in terms of iterators (which can be pointers):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // srand, rand
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

#define NSEGMENTS 100
#define MAX_NPXS 50
#define N 10000

// plain array approach
typedef struct {
    uint16_t index;
    uint16_t nvals;
    uint16_t vals[MAX_NPXS];
    double mean;
} a_segment_t;

// stl vector approach
typedef struct {
    uint16_t index;
    uint16_t nvals;
    vector<uint16_t> vals;
    uint32_t mean;
} b_segment_t;

void delta_time(struct timespec*, struct timespec*, struct timespec*);

template<class Iter>
uint16_t operation(Iter first, Iter last) {
    auto result = std::uint16_t(std::distance(first, last));
    // the operation (plain array approach)
    for( ; first != last ; ++first ) {
        auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(first->vals), std::begin(first->vals) + first->nvals, uint64_t(0), std::plus<>());
        first->mean = sum / first->nvals;
    }
    return result;
}


template<class Iter>
uint16_t print(Iter first, Iter last) {
    auto result = std::uint16_t(std::distance(first, last));
    // print data (plain array approach)
    for( ; first != last ; ++first ) {
        cout << "index : " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << first->index;
        cout << "\tnval : " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << first->nvals;
        cout << "\tvals : [";
        for_each(std::begin(first->vals), std::begin(first->vals) + first->nvals, [](const auto& val)
        {
            cout << val << ",";
        });
        cout << "\b]" << endl;
    }
    return result;
}

void delta_time(struct timespec* t1, struct timespec* t2, struct timespec* dt) {
    if ((t2->tv_nsec - t1->tv_nsec) < 0) {
        dt->tv_sec = t2->tv_sec - t1->tv_sec - 1;
        dt->tv_nsec = t2->tv_nsec - t1->tv_nsec + 1000000000;
    } else {
        dt->tv_sec = t2->tv_sec - t1->tv_sec;
        dt->tv_nsec = t2->tv_nsec - t1->tv_nsec;
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    uint16_t nsegments = NSEGMENTS;
    uint16_t nsegment = 0;
    uint16_t i = 0;

    //create an populate the segments with dummy data (plain array approach)
    a_segment_t* a_segments = new a_segment_t[nsegments];
    for( nsegment = 0; nsegment < nsegments; ++nsegment ) {
        a_segments[nsegment].index = nsegment;
        srand(nsegment);
        a_segments[nsegment].nvals = rand() % MAX_NPXS + 1;
        for(uint16_t nval = 0; nval < a_segments[nsegment].nvals; ++nval){
            a_segments[nsegment].vals[nval] = nval;
        }
    }

    //create an populate the segments with dummy data (stl vector approach)
    nsegment = 0;
    vector<b_segment_t> b_segments(nsegments);
    for (vector<b_segment_t>::iterator p_segment = b_segments.begin(); p_segment<b_segments.end(); ++p_segment) {
        p_segment->index = nsegment;
        srand(nsegment);
        p_segment->nvals = rand() % MAX_NPXS + 1;
        for(uint16_t nval = 0; nval < p_segment->nvals; ++nval){
            p_segment->vals.push_back(nval);
        }
        nsegment++;
    }

    // print(a_segments, a_segments + nsegments);
    // cout << "===================================" << endl;

    // print(b_segments.begin(), b_segments.end());
    // cout << "===================================" << endl;

    // ======================= plain array timing measure ========================
    struct timespec a_times[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        nsegments = operation(a_segments, a_segments + nsegments);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(a_times[i]));
    }
    // ===========================================================================

    // ========================= vector timing measure ===========================
    struct timespec b_times[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        nsegments = operation(b_segments.begin(), b_segments.begin() + nsegments);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(b_times[i]));
    }
    // ===========================================================================

    // =========================== timing console log ============================
    struct timespec a_deltatime[N], a_elapsedtime[N], b_deltatime[N], b_elapsedtime[N];
    cout << "\t\t  plain array\t\t       stl vector" << endl;
    cout << "frame #\telapsedtime\tdeltatime\telapsedtime\tdeltatime" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < N-1; i=i+1000) {
        delta_time(&(a_times[0]), &(a_times[i]), &(a_elapsedtime[i]));
        delta_time(&(a_times[i]), &(a_times[i+1]), &(a_deltatime[i]));
        delta_time(&(b_times[0]), &(b_times[i]), &(b_elapsedtime[i]));
        delta_time(&(b_times[i]), &(b_times[i+1]), &(b_deltatime[i]));
        cout << i << ",\t"
        << a_elapsedtime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << a_elapsedtime[i].tv_nsec << ",\t"
        << a_deltatime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << a_deltatime[i].tv_nsec << ",\t"
        << b_elapsedtime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << b_elapsedtime[i].tv_nsec << ",\t"
        << b_deltatime[i].tv_sec << "." << setfill('0') << setw(9) << b_deltatime[i].tv_nsec << endl;
    }
    // ===========================================================================

}
```

Yields expected results:

```
          plain array              stl vector
frame # elapsedtime deltatime   elapsedtime deltatime
0,  0.000000000,    0.000002000,    0.000000000,    0.000002000
1000,   0.001533000,    0.000001000,    0.001551000,    0.000002000
2000,   0.003061000,    0.000002000,    0.003096000,    0.000002000
3000,   0.004589000,    0.000001000,    0.004771000,    0.000002000
4000,   0.006255000,    0.000001000,    0.006433000,    0.000002000
5000,   0.007785000,    0.000002000,    0.007975000,    0.000001000
6000,   0.009326000,    0.000002000,    0.009494000,    0.000001000
7000,   0.010893000,    0.000002000,    0.011012000,    0.000001000
8000,   0.012435000,    0.000002000,    0.012650000,    0.000002000
9000,   0.014024000,    0.000002000,    0.014273000,    0.000001000
```

Answer (score 1):

The two versions aren't actually equivalent.

Firstly, your "array version" has `mean` as a `double`, and the "STL version" has `mean` as `uint32_t`.   For the two functions to be remotely equivalent, the calculation of `mean` needs to be the same.

Second, your "array version" uses array subscripting, whereas the STL version increments and dereferences iterators.     Since the compiler/optimiser will need to allow for more concerns (such as pointer aliasing) in the array version, it is probably unable to optimise performance as much.

Try turning your array version into something like;

```
uint16_t operation(uint16_t nsegments, a_segment_t* p_segments)
{
    uint64_t sum;
    for(a_segment *pseg = p_segments, *eseg = p_segments + nsegments; pseg < eseg; ++pseg)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(uint16_t *val = pseg->vals, *eval = pseg->vals + pseg->nvals; val < eval; ++val)
        {
            sum = sum + (*val);
        }
        p_seg->mean = sum/(pseg->nvals);
    }
    return nsegments;
}
```

This will (barring mistakes I've made in translating to this form - I haven' tested) give the same result, but will at least give the compiler a fighting chance of being able to apply the same type of performance optimisations to your "array version" as to the "STL version".

This sort of thing is one reason (of several) that the C++ standard algorithms work with iterators, rather than array indexing on containers like `vector`.  The compiler has a better chance of optimising performance.   Note that a pointer is a type of iterator.

Comment: is an array traversal faster (more optimizable for the compiler) if its done via pointer increments instead of array subscripts?